# vagrant plugin install error `gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby, vagrant

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-parallels
```

Installing the 'vagrant-parallels' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing little-plugger (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk,

and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/little-plugger-1.1.4.gem)

when I change the --plugin-source

```
 vagrant plugin install vagrant-parallels --plugin-source https://ruby.taobao.org/
```

The error is the same.
Then I try

```
gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'
```

Successfully installed little-plugger-1.1.4

Parsing documentation for little-plugger-1.1.4

Done installing documentation for little-plugger after 0 seconds

1 gem installed
Then

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-parallels --plugin-source https://ruby.taobao.org/
```

It still don't work

I try to change all the gemfile source

```
source "https://ruby.taobao.org
```

But It still don't work.
I use gem sources -l

```
$ gem sources -l
```

get follow:
    https://ruby.taobao.org/

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: you should paste the full error, generally there's some library missing that needs to be installed as dependencies (often zlib or others)

Answer (score 2):

I have a stupid way
first 
gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4' in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 
and then copy

```
sudo cp -r gems/little-plugger-1.1.4/ /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/
sudo cp -r specifications/little-plugger-1.1.4.gemspec /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/specifications
sudo cp -r doc/little-plugger-1.1.4 /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/doc
sudo cp cache/little-plugger-1.1.4.gem /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/cache
```

It worked.
But what other convenient way can set the gem install path

Comment: That worked for me! The only difference is that I had to run `gem environment` to find my gems path (using rvm here).