# How install vagrant-sphere plugin

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I have vagrant 1.7.2 and I need vagrant-vsphere plugin but when when I try the command: `vagrant pluging install vagrant-vpshere` show these error's message:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-vsphere' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Fetching source index from http://gems.hashicorp.com/
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using builder 3.2.2
Using gyoku 1.2.2
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.3.1
Using akami 1.2.2
Using bundler 1.7.11
Using hitimes 1.2.2
Using timers 4.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using ffi 1.9.10
Using childprocess 0.5.8
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using gssapi 1.0.3
Using hashicorp-checkpoint 0.1.4
Using httpclient 2.6.0.1
Using rack 1.6.0
Using httpi 0.9.7
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.4
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Using listen 2.8.4
Using little-plugger 1.1.4
Using log4r 1.1.10
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using logging 1.8.2
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using net-ssh 2.9.2
Using net-scp 1.1.2
Using net-sftp 2.1.2
Using nori 1.1.5
Using rb-kqueue 0.2.3
Using trollop 2.1.2
Using rbvmomi 1.8.2
Using rest-client 1.6.9
Using rubyntlm 0.1.1
Using wasabi 1.0.0
Using savon 0.9.5
Using uuidtools 2.1.5
Using wdm 0.1.0
Using winrm 1.1.3
Using vagrant 1.7.2

NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

An error occurred while installing vagrant-share (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install vagrant-share -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After these error I was installed manually gem vagrant-share 1.1.4 but I discovered that vagrant has plugin vagrant-share 1.1.3 as system plugin:

```
# vagrant plugin update vagrant-share
vagrant-share (1.1.3, system)
```

**The question**: How install vagrant-sphere plugin in consistency way with vagrant 1.7.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on answer of question: [vagrant plugin install error `gem install little-plugger -v '1.1.4'` succeeds before bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805193/vagrant-plugin-install-error-gem-install-little-plugger-v-1-1-4-succeeds-be/32805998#32805998):

But in my case I need copy resource of vagrant-share gem:

1. `gem install vagrant-share '1.1.5'`
2. `sudo cp -r gems/vagrant-share-1.1.5/ /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/`
3. `sudo cp -r specifications/vagrant-share-1.1.5.gemspec /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/specifications`
4. `sudo cp -r doc/vagrant-share-1.1.5 /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/doc`
5. `sudo cp cache/vagrant-share-1.1.5.gem /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/cache`

Then you can execute without problems: `vagrant pluging install vagrant-vpshere`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `vagrant-share 1.1.3` installed, you can either do

1. `vagrant plugin install vagrant-share --plugin-version 1.1.4`

This will install version 1.1.4 on your system

2. `vagrant plugin update vagrant-share`

This will update your vagrant-share plugin (to 1.1.5 at the time we speak)

Then you should be able to complete installation for vagrant-vpshere

Comment: I try your steps but the output of step1 show the same error message related to vagrant-share 1.1.4

Comment: can you run `vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-share` before then

Comment: nop because vagrant-share is a system plugin and I can't uninstalled without errors

Comment: weird, works for me `fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-share
Uninstalling the 'vagrant-share' plugin...`

Comment: ohhh but when you execute `vagrant plugin list` what the output? what's your vagrant version?

Comment: sorry I mixed-up, so right you cannot uninstall, I did uninstall a particular version - I had installed `vagrant plugin install vagrant-share --plugin-version 1.1.4` to get `fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-share (1.1.4)
  - Version Constraint: 1.1.4
` then I can do `fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-share
Uninstalling the 'vagrant-share' plugin...
fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant plugin list ...
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
fhenri@machine:~$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97992/discussion-between-kikicarbonell-and-frederic-henri).